# How to iterate through Elementtree using namespaces

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have been trying to parse through an xml document using ElementTree in python to modify one of the elements, however I keep running into issues due to namespaces.

I can get all the tags from my xml document with

```
data = open('query-user-by-name.xml').read()
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for item in root.iter():
    print(item.tag)
```

which gives me:

```
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}query
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}filter
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}equal
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}matching
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}path
{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}value
```

I have created a dictionary with a namespace:

```
namespaces = {'ns':'http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3'}
```

but when I try to find the element I am searching for with

```
data = open('query-user-by-name.xml').read()
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for item in root.iter('ns:value', namespaces):
    print(item.tag)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: iter() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

It seems like I am giving only two arguments and not three. What am I doing wrong to properly iterate through these elements using the namespace?

*Edit: Here is my query-all-users.xml file:

```
<query xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
        xmlns="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3">
<filter>
        <equal>
        <matching>polyStringNorm</matching>
                <path>c:name</path>
                <value>lilpotter</value>
        </equal>
</filter>
</query>
```

Comment: `iter()` is a method, all methods get passed the instance reference by default (usually named `self`). Consider the message to be *"`iter() takes at most 1 argument + instance reference (2 + instance given)`"*

Comment: `iter` is documented as taking only one argument (beyond the instance reference): `tag`    https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter   Maybe try using `iterfind` which takes an additional `namespaces` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @gill Hamilton, you should use `iterfind`, but with a XPath expression, for instance: ".//ns:value".

Here is a full example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

content = u"""\
<query xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
        xmlns="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3">
<filter>
        <equal>
        <matching>polyStringNorm</matching>
                <path>c:name</path>
                <value>lilpotter</value>
        </equal>
</filter>
</query>"""

root = ET.fromstring(content)

NS = {'ns': 'http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3'}

for item in root.iterfind(".//ns:value", NS):
    print(item.tag)

# -> {http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}value
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to return anything when I try it.

Comment: `iterfind` doesn't seem to find anything, however I can find the element I'm looking for by including the namespace like:

    `for item in root.iter('{http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3}value'):
        print(item.tag)`

But I can't work out how to find it using a namespace dictionary.

Comment: Can you post an sample of "query-user-by-name.xml"?

Comment: Yes @Laurent, I have added it to my question, thank you.

Comment: Actually, you need to use a XPath expression, like ".//ns:value". See my edit

Comment: You were absolutely correct. Using the XPath expression I was able to successfully find that element. Thank you for your help with this issue!